# How to have text appear with an image in two separate columns?

Tags: beamer, graphics, columns

I would like to have an image appear with each main bullet point (I am trying to show the study species in question for each objective). Therefore, once "Species X" appears in the left column, Species X graphic will appear in the right column simultaneously. Below is my current code, where the text appears step by step in the left column, and then the images appear after the text has been run through.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=15]
\frametitle{The Great Lakes}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \pause \item Native
        \begin{itemize}
        \pause \item Species 1
                \begin{itemize}
                \pause \item Information 1
                \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \pause \item Introduced
        \begin{itemize}
        \pause \item Species 2
                \begin{itemize}
                \pause \item Information 2
                \end{itemize}
        \pause \item Species 3
                \begin{itemize}
                \pause \item Information 1
                \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
     \begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
         \centering
        \includegraphics[height=5em]{Species 1}

    \includegraphics[height=5em]{Species 2}

    \includegraphics[height=5em]{Species 3}
     \end{column}
     \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Basic Ideas**

The overlay or overprint effect can be achieved in many ways. The [beamer user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) spends more than ten pages (Section 9) on this issue.

The following is one of the possible solutions. You may want to use
the `overprint` environment along with the `\onslide` command if you
want to control the gradual appearance in other ways.

**The Code**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=15]
  \frametitle{The Great Lakes}

  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item <1->Native
        \begin{itemize}
        \item <1->Species 1
          \begin{itemize}
          \item <1->Information 1
          \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
      \item <2->Introduced
        \begin{itemize}
        \item <2->Species 2
          \begin{itemize}
          \item <2->Information 2
          \end{itemize}
        \item <3->Species 3
          \begin{itemize}
          \item <3->Information 1
          \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics<1->[height=5em]{Species1}

      \includegraphics<2->[height=5em]{Species2}

      \includegraphics<3->[height=5em]{Species3}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]

**Further Tweaks**

- You will want to align the image positions with the corresponding texts.